# Showing the Unit Circle is Connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

One way to show that the unit circle is connected is to use the map $f: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$. Since $f$ is a continuous map and $[0, 2\pi]$ is connected, the image must be connected.

I was wondering how to show the unit circle is connected by the definition. My textbook gives the definition of disconnected as follows: Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(S,d)$. The set $E$ is disconnected if there are disjoint open subsets $U_1, U_2$ in $S$ such that $E \subseteq U_1 \cup U_2$, $E \cap U_1 \neq \emptyset$ and $E \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset$.

Then a set $E$ is connected if for all disjoint open subsets $U_1, U_2$ in $S$ we have either $E \supset U_1 \cup U_2$ or $E \cap U_1 = \emptyset$ or $E \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. But I see that it is possible to have 2 disjoint open subsets where all 3 conditions fail.

Consider an open ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $(-1, 0)$ and another one at $(1,0)$. It is clear that all there conditions of a connected set fail.

Where have I messed up?

Comment: Your definition of disconnected isn't correct; you also need $U_1\cap U_2\cap E=\varnothing$ (the point being that you've then divided $E$ into disjoint non-empty open sets $E\cap U_1$ and $E\cap U_2$, where "open" means in the subspace topology).

Comment: @MattPressland: For some reason my book doesn't mention that statement...

Comment: @Student: Can you show that that ball is connected arcwise?

Comment: The negation of $E\subseteq U_1\cup U_2$ is not $E\supset U_1\cup U_2$, but $E\nsubseteq U_1\cup U_2$. The subset relation does not give a total order.

Comment: @Student I'm in fact just noticing that you said "disjoint open subsets", which covers what I said (although in pratcice they don't actually need to be disjoint, just disjoint in $E$). Your problem is actually the one pointed out by celtschk - the unit circle isn't contained in the union of your two subsets, and it needs to be for them to give a counterexample.